# Create mysql function

Tags: mysql

I want to create a function with below query,but occur error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getOnlineUserTraffic (x1 VARCHAR(32)) 
RETURNS FLOAT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist FLOAT;
  SET dist = SELECT UsedCreditTraffic FROM uonlineuser WHERE UserName=x1
  RETURN dist;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

//    userName= char with length=32

//    UsedCreditTraffic  = float

Comment: By all means, don't tell us _what_ error message you got ;)

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select UsedCreditTraffic from uonlineuser where UserName=x1
  RETURN dist;
END' at line 6

Comment: `SELECT UsedCreditTraffic INTO dist FROM uonlineuser WHERE UserName=x1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getOnlineUserTraffic$$

CREATE FUNCTION getOnlineUserTraffic(x1 VARCHAR(32)) 
RETURNS FLOAT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist FLOAT;
  SET dist = (SELECT UsedCreditTraffic FROM uonlineuser WHERE UserName=x1);
  RETURN dist;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d9f1/1)</kbd>

Comment: @user3780058: I don't understand question. Where do you want to use the function, you can give an example?

Comment: I can use this query in sqlyog but how to use it in programming language

Comment: @user3780058: Every programming language has its own way of executing queries involving MySQL stored routines.